# Why is there a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, gtk, char

I'm still having problems in my GTK program.

When I click the encode (or decode) button I get the error message:

> Segmentation Fault

I think the problem comes from functions: `ret` and `encode` but can't find it.

```
    //..
    //gets the first argument(buf)
    tx1=gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
    //...
    //gets the second argument(pass)
    tx2=gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
    //....
    //signal to callback function encode when button clicked
    g_signal_connect(but,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(encode(tx1,tx2)),NULL);
    // ...
    //convert const char* to char*
    char* ret (const char *bd){
    char *c = new char[12];
    strcpy(c,bd);
    return c;
} 

//encode function
char encode(const char ebuf[],const char epass[]) {
    //This is the complete function I wrote and I am still having the error.
    char *buf=ret(ebuf);
    char *pass=ret(epass);
}
```

Comment: What are the strlens of ebuf and epass? And why not using `std::string`?

Comment: why not using debugger?

Comment: it seems like i did mistake in GTK according to what rodrigo said

Answer (score 1):

This line makes no sense:

```
g_signal_connect(but,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(encode(tx1,tx2)),NULL);
```

You are calling `encode()` with some arguments, it returns a `char` value, (undefined by the way) and you cast that `char` into a `GCallback`, that is a pointer-to-function. Then, when the button is clicked Gtk+ will try to call your `char` which is obviously not a valid function and hence the segmentation fault.

Not sure what you want to do, but you have to play [by the rules](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked), and the rules say that the `"clicked"` callback should be a pointer-to-function with this prototype:

```
void f(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data);
```

Other than that and you are playing really dangerous.

**EXAMPLE CODE AHEAD**

Say, for example that you want to call function `encode` with a `char*` as argument. You could do it like this:

```
void clicked_encode(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    char *d = static_cast<char*>(user_data);
    encode(d);
}
```

And to register the callback

```
g_signal_connect(but, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clicked_encode), text);
```

That assumes that the memory pointed to by `text` lives at least as long as the callback. If that is not the case, you make a copy, but then you have to remember to free it:

```
char *d = strdup(text);
g_signal_connect_data(but, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clicked_encode), d, free_text, 0);

//and the deleter function
void free_text(gpointer *data, GClosure *)
{
    char *d = static_cast<char*>(data);
    free(d);
}
```

Naturally, you may need more than one parameter in your function, but you can only pass one pointer. The solution is to define a struct (or a class, you are using C++) with everything in it:

```
FancyClass *d = new FancyClass(...);
g_signal_connect_data(but, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clicked_encode), d, free_fancy_class, 0);

void clicked_encode(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    FancyClass *d = static_cast<FancyClass*>(user_data);
    encode(d);
}

void free_fancy_class(gpointer *data, GClosure *)
{
    FancyClass *d = static_cast<FancyClass*>(data);
    delete d;
}
```

Hey! You can even make `encode()` a member function of `FancyClass`. The possibilities are endless!

I hope thit will put you on the right track...

Comment: ya bro...im new to gtk...i read about in 2 days ..and i started coding the app on linux ...can u help me do that ?

Comment: @user2355950: I'd be glad to help, but you should clarify what you want to do. It also helps to look into some tutorial... Anyway take a look into the update answer.

Comment: i think thats close enough to put me on the right track...Thnx very much brother ..

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to have more dynamically sized character strings, use strncpy to limit the number of characters to be copied.

Comment: true ... i can limit it to 12 chars